# Check Date greater than 2 days from today's date javascript

Tags: javascript, html, date

I need to check the date is two days greater than current date increment the count and display

JS code:

> ```
> > var exceeds = 0;
> >          var date = "25-02-2015";
> >          var today = new Date();
> >           if((new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()+2))>date) {    exceed+=1; }
> > 
> > console.log(exceeds);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 

today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
document.write(today);
var currentDate = "03/23/2015";
if(today <= currentDate ){
alert('yes');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your date to Unix TimeStamp, which is the millisecond from 1970-01-01 00:00:00 to your specific date.
Well, there is the code

```
var yourDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 02, 25)).getTime(); //Get the timestamp 
var today = new Date().getTime();         
if(today - yourDate > 60 * 60 * 1000 * 24 * 2){alert('greater than 2 days')}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var exceeds = 0;
var date = "25-02-2015", date_val  = date.split("-");

// Getting timestamp of date
var otherDate = new Date(+date_val[2], +date_val[1], +date_val[0]).getTime();

// Get the timestamp for 2 days from now:
var timestamp = new Date().getTime() + (2* 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
if(otherDate>timestamp) exceeds++;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to parse the datetime instead of converting to timestamp:

```
const yourDate = Date.parse('2023-06-26 12:08:15');
const today = new Date().getTime();         
if(today - yourDate > 60 * 60 * 1000 * 24 * 2){
  alert('greater than 2 days')
}
```